# Using Selenium web driver i cant pass certain http authenitication credentials in the driver.get() method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use the URL to pass a HTTP Basic Authentication Check with Selenium WebDriver in Chrome.
To open the site i use code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from src.pom import settings

PATH = settings.chromedriver_path

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://username:Ziel#0Fehler@www.google.com')
```

However this gives me
`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument`

If i remove the # or the : between the username and the HTTP Auth Password the error doesnt get thrown but I need this exact data for the HTTP Auth

Comment: the url should be something like that: driver.get("https://<username>:<password>@www.google.com")

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
import urllib.parse

password = 'Ziel#0Fehler'
password = urllib.parse.quote(password)

driver.get(f'https://username:{password}@www.google.com')
```

you have url encode password as it has special characters that have special meaning in url eg: #